# Quick launch left menu disappeared for specific list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-list

The Quick Launch menu that appears to the left suddenly disappeared for a single list in my SharePoint site. When I go to site settings, the Quick Launch is still enabled. It's simply disappeared from this one list. How can I restore it?

Comment: Is it a communication site?

Comment: Quick questions: 1. What is the version of SharePoint you are using? 2. What is the site template you are using? 3. Do you have any customization on this list or recently changed the page layout? One more suggestion: Try opening this list using another browser or machine.